# View properties resetting after view change

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I've been trying to make this work for a while now with no chance, every time I change from view to view, the view's variables and content are reset to 'default' e.g if in a view I changed a label's text field from the default 'Label' to 'Hello, and then change views, once I come back to the same view, the text will be 'Label' again.

The only way I've gotten around this so far is to set a static string and then change Label.text to string in viewDidLoad. I just KNOW that this isn't the way to do it. I have a hunch that it's to do with how I transition from view to view, (allocating and initiating etc.)

Current way I transition:

```
FirstView.h:
@interface FirstView : Engine
@property(nonatomic, readwrite) MainGameDisplay *secondView;

FirstView.m:
@implementation FirstView

- (IBAction)StartGame:(id)sender 
{ 
    if (! self.secondView)
    self.secondView = [[MainGameDisplay alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController: self.secondView animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

And MainGameDisplay:

```
MainGameDisplay.h:
@class ViewController;

@interface MainGameDisplay : Engine
@property (strong) ViewController *firstPage;

MainGameDisplay.m:
@implementation MainGameDisplay

- (IBAction)returnToHome:(id)sender {
    if (!self.firstPage)
        self.firstPage = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [self presentViewController: self.firstPage animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

What I would like is to not have to set all of the values again through viewDidLoad, I just cant see it as being a good programming style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in your suspicions about what's gone wrong.  Although you call your method `returnToHome:` you aren't really returning anywhere but rather stacking a new copy of `ViewController` on top of whatever you already have.

To actually go back, the opposite of `presentViewController:` is `dismissViewControllerAnimated:`.  Try using that inside your `MainGameDisplay` class when the button is pressed to go back.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! But I can already spot a future problem. If I go from MainGameDisplay to SecondView, then straight to ThirdView, if I go straight back to MainGameDisplay, wont that be a new instance? What I'm trying to say is, is there a way I can have all view instances intertwined with each other under one 'Superclass' of some sort so that I always go to the same one.

Comment: If you're using **modal** controllers, it's **usually** best to only have two levels.  The modal concept is that there's something that happens normally and then this modal thing that interrupts it before it can carry on.  For your example, life would be simpler if you can structure the program so that you go: main->second->main->third->main....  That may mean using data or notifications (or something) to tell main what it's supposed to do next.

Comment: For cases where you need a stack of controllers and the ability to go back one or more levels, that pretty much defines the purpose of a navigation controller with push and pop (instead of present and dismiss).